# Impliment a changeStream with aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, changestream

I'm trying to hack around a MongoDB driver that [doesn't yet implement changeStreams](https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/issues/97) by using an aggregation pipeline which it looks like I can do [according to this document](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/9ec7093cd5b4f9bfef8d4353d07cd51cf322bd98/source/change-streams/change-streams.rst).

If I just want every change made to a collection, what do I put as the `Value` to `"$changeStream"`?

Comment: I believe you are inquiring about change streams in the MongoDB Rust driver.  Most of the drivers have change streams implemented but I'm not sure about the MongoDB Rust driver in particular.

Comment: Actually it is the community maintained Haskell Driver for MongoDB. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB